# Table tr background image not work on webkit browser

Tags: css, webkit

`tr` having background image which shows perfect in all browser except *webkit browsers*
(Google Chrome & Apple Safari). The background image is repeating from each `th`.

```
table > tbody > tr.fieldheader {
    background:url(../images/main-sprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    height:37px;
    width:900px;
    background-position:left -1062px;
    border-radius:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What is "background-position:left -1062px;" doing there? It looks like you have mixed up 2 different properties and that might well be causing the error.

Also it is good practice to put quotes around URLs in css as some browsers have a problem without them

```
background:url("../images/main-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

Comment: I am using a sprite image, for which I'm using background-position css, I changed the css and put an normal image in the tr but it still having the same issue.

Comment: I solve the issue.. I remove background image from tr and put it in table background image and now it's working fine.